# Listing users in a distribution list when using mail enabled security groups

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook, distribution-lists

Exchange Server 2010

I am in the process of migrating to using mail enabled security groups to populate mail distribution groups.  I would like to hide the groups from being listed.  So far I have accomplished this.

Friendlyname_List@site.com <- Security-group (mail enabled, uncheck "list in address book")

What is not working however is the ability for people to expand Friendlyname_List@site.com in outlook and see the members.

Email flow is working fine - it gets the email to the right users, but people who want to see "who exactly" they are emailing are confronted with an error: Cannot perform the requested operation. The command selected is not valid for this recipient. There was an error expanding the list.  The list was not fully expanded.

Security group is universal.  In OWA if I right-click > properties I see nothing listed.

Comment: I would think this is because the list you are trying to expand is hidden. Posted as comment since I'm on my phone and can't back this statement up with a source.  May we assume the experience is the same in OWA?

Comment: @blaughw Being hidden was not the only issue, our GAL lists only addresses with "Company" set, so when I tested "list in address book" I didnt see a change.  Tests with both company and list allow for expansion, however it requires my security groups to be listed.  I suppose my problem now is "How can I expand a group without listing it in the GAL"